# Why do floorball balls have holes and how do they function?

Tags: floorball

I'm a floorball player, and recently for my Science Presentation about the Science of floorball, I was thinking of why floorball balls have holes on them. On the ball itself, there are twenty-six holes, and numerous dents on it. I have done some research on it, but I can only come across answers on why the ball have dents on it. The floorball ball is quite like a golf ball/wiffle ball/ pickle ball, but I am still unable to find an answer on why the floorball ball has twenty-six holes on them. The small dimples on it reduce air resistance. The dimples on the ball aid in the reduction of air resistance and friction with the surface. But what about the holes?